# Angular Type '{ domain: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | Color'

Tags: angular, angular12, ngx-charts

I am using ngx-charts with Angular 12 and I'm getting this error message then I use this:

```
colorScheme = {
  domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
};
```

The error message is:

```
Type '{ domain: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | Color'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ngx-charts version 18 or below.

The scheme type [scheme]="colorScheme", is asking for a string but the type you are providing is an object.

The latest version 19 or above as scheme type is of string | color.

Comment: The code I provided I got from their own demos ...strange :( By string...do you mean an array of strings? Because I need to add multiple hex codes

Comment: String as in single string not an array. Before string was of type any so there was not any problem. But now it is declare as of type string | color.

Comment: please can you elaborate more on that I'm facing the same issue, with ngx-charts. how did you assign to it? when I just pass the string the chart doesn't load

Answer (score 10):

ngx-charts version 19 or above accepts only types string or Color ([from here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/e2e10b5c9efd7c51aa317dd648955355118d9442/projects/swimlane/ngx-charts/src/lib/utils/color-sets.ts#L3)), and to expand on another answer:

- String examples include `"cool"`, `"natural"`, `"vivid"`, etc from the preset color schemes [in this file](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/e2e10b5c9efd7c51aa317dd648955355118d9442/projects/swimlane/ngx-charts/src/lib/utils/color-sets.ts).
- Color example to set your own custom scheme:

```js
import { Color, ScaleType } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
export class foo {
  colorScheme: Color = {
    name: 'myScheme',
    selectable: true,
    group: ScaleType.Ordinal,
    domain: ['#f00', '#0f0', '#0ff'],
  };
}
```

```html
<ngx-charts-area-chart 
 ...
 [scheme]="colorScheme"
></ngx-charts-area-chart>
```

Comment: this is better solutoin, agrees?+1

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
import { Color, ScaleType } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';

colorScheme: Color = { 
    domain: ['#99CCE5', '#FF7F7F'], 
    group: ScaleType.Ordinal, 
    selectable: true, 
    name: 'Customer Usage', 
};
```

[Github: Typing of Color is incorrect](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1673#issuecomment-1046530451)